# Website not reading the correct local json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have made a HTML site that reads a .json with javascript/jQuery and writes to it with PHP.
I then have a c++ backend that writes and reads to the same .json.
I want to be able to send what button is selected by the players to the c++.

The .json that javascript reads isn't always the .json that I have modified with PHP or C++.
It won't always have the updated data, the time to get the updated data can be instant, a few seconds or e few minutes.

I have tried to remove caching and I have checked that the file gets updated

To load the .json on the website I use:

```
var $JSONList = $('#JSONList');

  $.getJSON("json/playerMode.json", function(json) {
      console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
      var stringed = JSON.stringify(json);
      var response = JSON.parse(stringed);
      console.log(response); // this will show the info it in firebug console

      $.each(response, function(i, itt){

          $JSONList.append( "</br>" + itt.Name + " has pressed: " + itt.Button + " :(())");
      })

  });
```

This is called by a `<button>`

Since this sometimes won't load the updated .json, is there some way that I can force javascript to load the local .json again?

Comment: Where is the local JSON? Could you explain that behavior a little more in your question? :)

Comment: A quick fix for forcing new data to be served is to add a `?timetamp=[timestamp_here]` to the url being called. Alternatively you can use $.ajax and set `cache: false` in the options.

Comment: The local JSON is in a subfolder to the main.php.
I'll try the timestamp method

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make the assumption this url works - except the caching issue and address that and other things as noted.

- Change from the shortcut `"json/playerMode.json"` to `$ajax`
- Force to NOT cache the results
- Added a `fail` just in case
- fixed syntax for `"<br />"`
- removed unneeded code as the JSON would be parsed already as long as it is valid. IF it is not valid JSON and it only returns "a string, that looks like JSON", you should use `dataType: "text json"` to force jQuery conversion/parse 
  or consider using a converter (see below)
- MIGHT need `header('Content-Type: application/json')` for PHP
- if you are NOT returning a true JSON string, use a converter to make it into one, see **Using Converters** here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

This from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> **Note**: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET
>   parameters.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "json/playerMode.json",
  cache: false,
  data: "",
  dataType: "json" // force automatic parse of the JSON string returned
}).done(function(json) {
  console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
  // should not need
  // var stringed = JSON.stringify(json);
  // not needed, see above
  // var response = JSON.parse(json);
  //console.log(response); // this will show the info it in firebug console
  //$JSONList - what is this? it should be in here somewhere...so I did that
  let $JSONList = $('#JSONList');
  // should be parsed already, so changed to that
  $.each(json, function(i, itt) {
    $JSONList.append("<br />" + itt.Name + " has pressed: " + itt.Button + " :(())");
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="JSONList"></div>
```